# How can I get a check mark beside UIPickerView labels?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

The `UIPickerView` that appears in Safari has a check mark beside the current choice. Is there a built-in way to get this, or do I have to program it up myself? If I do have to create it, can anyone point me to some code to do this? Thanks[image: check mark or tick]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [`-pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW2) from the UIPickerViewDelegate.

You have to create a view, that contains a UIButton with the checkmark image, and return it from `-pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`

Comment: can you please tell how did you implemented above design....?
urgent required.....

Answer (score 6):

Here is some official sample code for customizing UIPicker view:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html

In particular, refer to classes PickerViewController.{h, m} , CustomPickerDataSource.{h, m} and CustomView.{h, m} in the example. You can create a similar custom UIPickerView with a tick image which gets displayed only to the left for the selected item and change the text color of selected item.
Also, remember to set `myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = NO;` to remove the semi-transparent bar above the selected item.